# Avoid Multiple Select on an Activerecord

Tags: ruby

I currently have the following code to find all the unique IDs of comments placed by a user. This works "fine". However, it's really slow for users with a lot of comments and I'm trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way of handling this as it doesn't seem to be the best solution.

```
  def find_unique_user_grades
    @comments = []
    @environment.users.includes(:comments).map(&:comments).select do |comments|
      comments.select { |comment| @comments.push(comment.id) }
    end
    @comments.uniq!
  end
```

I'm hoping someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should always prefer to do this in the database, not in Ruby. The code you've posted will load all `users` from the database, and then convert the raw row data to ActiveRecord objects, which is (comparatively) extremely expensive. You don't need any of that data to join through to `comments`. Then, you'll do the same for every user's `comments` (query and create ActiveRecord objects) and again, you don't need *any* of that to get at the comment's `id` column.

What you're after (assuming I've guessed correctly at the shape your schema) is a simply `join` followed by a `pluck`. This will run a single query and return a single array of numbers, without any of the cost of loading `users`, creating objects, loading `comments`, creating objects, or iterating in Ruby.

Finally, it will also perform the `distinct` query in the database, where it can take advantage of any relevant indexes, rather than `uniq`ing in Ruby.

The correct query is something near to:

```
 @environment.users.joins(:comments).distinct.pluck('comments.id')
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly and it improves the query time a lot.